# importing javascript modules from a third party library

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mapbox-gl-js

In my code I already use the mapbox-gl-js library to create a map by using this import:

```
let mapboxgl = require('mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js')
```

which works fine.

Now I would like to use the 'create' function that exists within mapbox-gl.js in its dom module: [this one to be more precise.](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/b9e10b939c6a3fe5d7ecac209f751b4871970ede/src/util/dom.js)

I was hoping I could simply use this:

```
mapboxgl.dom.create(arguments)
```

but then I get errormessage:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
```

Can I use the 'create function' of the library and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you are actually `require`-ing is the [`index.js` file](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/b9e10b939c6a3fe5d7ecac209f751b4871970ede/src/index.js), which does not export the `dom` symbol, because this is an internal utility of mapbox. You can always copy the file `dom.js` and use it if you need to, but mapbox doesn't expose this file for you to use.

**EDIT:**

If you are determined to use the file, you can require it directly, although it is not advisable, since mapbox could decide to change or remove the function at any version upgrade. In my case I installed the package via npm, so I required it like so `let mbDom = require('mapbox-gl/src/util/dom');`.

While this is possible, it is far from advisable.

Comment: Great, thanks. Could you maybe explain why in this fiddle https://jsbin.com/matayut/edit?js,console,output the line ```mapboxgl.util.extend(defaultGeoPositionOptions, this.options && this.options.positionOptions || {})``` works? The fiddle uses a 'html import' of the library but still I would not expect it to work, or what is different from above?

Comment: `util` is exported, `dom` is not. `mapboxgl.util` pulls from the `util/util.js` file, which does not expose the `dom` module

Comment: You are correct. Noting here that `util` is no longer exported in recent releases. https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/1408